# Git and Minified Files

Tags: git

I am using React with webpack to manage my app. The output of webpack is a minified file that contains my React components with their logic. Whenever I make a change, small or big, then the minified file will update. I do not want to see the changes on git, but I still want the file to be uploaded onto my repo. Is there a way to treat the file as a binary?

I know that if I have a `.gitattributes` file, with `<file> binary`.

Then when I preform git diff , the return is binary diff. But how do I make github/bitbucket see that it is also a binary through the web ui.

Comment: have you checked if github/bitbucket respect your .gitattributes? It could be that they do.

Comment: but in general binary artifacts do not belong to VCS like git, there are dedicated systems for those

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't commit the bundle file in the first place. Anyway, if you really want it to be available in the repository, make the first commit to include it. Then add it to the .gitignore file so it will no longer be cared about:

**.gitignore**

`some/where/bundle.js   <-- name of your bundle file`

Comment: How would you put the bundled file into the application then?

Comment: If it is ignored by git, then how do you push updates??! You are then forced to upload them via FTP

Comment: @Black, as I understood, one of the ways is to run build scripts on the server after you pull source files.